# How to hide this menus from wordpress admin menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How do I hide the menus below from wordpress admin menu except for Admin:

```
    admin.php?page=booki/index.php
    admin.php?page=booki/managegcal.php
    admin.php?page=booki/userhistory.php
    admin.php?page=booki/cancelledbookings.php
    admin.php?page=booki/reminders.php
    admin.php?page=booki/stats.php
```

I tried this for first one but not worked:

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'nstrm_remove_admin_submenus', 999 );
    function nstrm_remove_admin_submenus() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'booki/index.php' );
     }
```

This menus are made by wordpress Booki plugin:
www.booki.io

Comment: You can use this light plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu/

Answer (score 0):

I checked the plugin demo and the first admin menu on your list is the main/top admin menu page, so if you remove it the whole menu will disappear.

If you really want to remove the whole menu, this should work:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'so_40959455_admin_menu', 999);

function so_40959455_admin_menu() {

  remove_menu_page('booki/index.php');
}
```

If you just want to remove the other submenus, this should work:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'so_40959455_admin_menu', 999);

function so_40959455_admin_menu() {

  remove_submenu_page('booki/index.php', 'booki/managegcal.php');
  remove_submenu_page('booki/index.php', 'booki/userhistory.php');
  remove_submenu_page('booki/index.php', 'booki/cancelledbookings.php');
  remove_submenu_page('booki/index.php', 'booki/reminders.php');
  remove_submenu_page('booki/index.php', 'booki/stats.php');
}
```

Comment: You can use this light plugin. wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu